# Question about projections in normed vector spaces and topological direct sum

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification

I want to show the following:

Let $E$ be a normed vector space, $P$ a projection i.e. P is a linear and continuous map $E \rightarrow E$.

Then we can write $E=ker(P) \oplus im (P)$ in a topological sense, i.e.

given a sequence $(u_n)_n$ in $E$, then $u_n$ converges to $0$ iff its representation in the direct sum converges to $0$.

My attempt:
From linear algebra we know that we can (uniquely) write $u=v_1+v_2$ for $v_1 \in ker (P)$, $v_2 \in im(P)$.

Since $ker(P)=im(Id-P)$, we get $v_1=(Id-P)u$ and $v_2=Pu$ (because applying $(Id-P)$ on $u$ gets us the unique "component" in $ker(P)$ and applying $P$ to $u$ gets us the unique "component" in $im(P)$.
Since $Id-P$ and $P$ are continuous, it follows that $u_n \rightarrow 0$ iff $(Pu_n)_n \rightarrow 0$ and $((Id-P)(u_n))_n \rightarrow 0 $.

Question: Is this correct?

Comment: It is correct, but you can slightly shorten the reasoning. We have $x=(x-Px)+Px.$ The first term belongs to $\ker P,$ while the second to ${\rm Im}\,P.$ If $u_n\to 0$ then both corresponding terms tend to $0.$ The intersection of $\ker P$ and $ {\rm Im}\,P$ is trivial hence $X$ is the direct sum of these subspaces.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Thank you !

Comment: You don't need sequences. Simply note that the two components of your bijection $E\to\ker P\times{\rm im}\,P$ are continuous (and of course the inverse map ($+$) is continuous).